Unified accounts / AccountId20
Is there any parachain template to start with , that uses unified accounts as default like moonbeam ?

Recently, OpenZeppelin applied for a grant.
I believe this is the best beginning.
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/polkadot-evm-runtime-template

This repo worked for me and is not using moonbeam fork
https://github.com/freeverseio/laos/tree/main
